# Is there a "Moore's law" type function, that has been fitted to the Cardano blockchain size as a function of time?

Tags: cardano-node, daedalus, blockchain, blocksize

In technology, when something is growing quickly and monotonically over time, we often fit the data over time to a curve and make claims like "the doubling time of the number of transistors in a computer is about 2 years", the most famous case probably being Moore's law, in which graphs like these are constantly being updated:

[image]

In quantum computing we have Rose's law, which talks about the doubling of the number of qubits in the D-Wave quantum annealers:

[image]

When drafting my answer to this question: [Why Is Daedalus Mainnet taking so long to Sync My Transaction History with the Blockchain?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4238/149), I found a related question on the Cardano Stack Exchange: [How big is the Cardano blockchain (now and in the future)?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/279/149), and it seems that this question is asked over and over and over again, at least on Reddit:

[image]

I was quite intrigued, that at the time of the Stack Exchange question in May 2021, the answer was only 8.5GB, and now in October 2021 it's about 16GB. Therefore, since people have asked the same question on Reddit so many times, I'm sure I could plot the Cardano blockchain size over time myself, but I wonder if anyone's been doing it at somewhat regular intervals, or if there's even been a "curve of best fit" done for such data?

Comment: Really interesting question, I guess it remains open until some brave techie brain dives into data mining. We have Cardano data queryable through BigQuery now so... https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2022/07/01/cardano-data-on-bigquery/